# Proper apps permissions from azure AD to grant access on Microsoft Graph

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Proper apps permissions from azure AD to grant access on Microsoft Graph where we can extract users emails information like To, From, Cc, Bcc, Subject.

Tried to grant all access but still encountering an access denied error.

None

Expected result will show users emails information like To, From, Cc, Bcc, Subject.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to use the [Microsoft Graph - Get message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), it returns the [message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/message?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) object which has the properties you want.

If you want to call the Microsoft Graph without a user, you need the **Application permission** `Mail.Read`. You just need to create an Azure AD Application and grant the permission for it, the application permission `Mail.Read` need admin consent, so don't forget to grant admin consent, about consent an application, see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-user-consent#grant-admin-consent-when-registering-an-app-in-the-azure-portal). For more details about all the steps, see [Get access without a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service).

If you want to call the Microsoft Graph  on behalf of a user, you need the **Delegated permission** `Mail.Read`, more details see [Get access on behalf of a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user).

**Besides**, if you want to get a message in another user's mail folder, please note the information as below,  see [Get message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

[image]